# Spring WebClient and shared client credential token for all requests

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I tried to use Spring WebClient and Spring Security OAuth2 Client for communication between two applications. I need to use OAuth2 Client Credentials grant type and use the same credentials and the same token for all requests between these applications. In the OAuth2 terminology resource owner is an application A itself and resource server is an application B (it is Keycloak Admin API). I use Spring Boot auto configuration from application.yaml and servlet environment. So I implemented it like this:

```java
WebClient buildWebClient(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
    OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository, String clientName) {
  final ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2Client = new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
      clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);
  oauth2Client.setDefaultClientRegistrationId(clientName);

  return WebClient.builder()
      .apply(oauth2Client.oauth2Configuration())
      .build();
}
```

I found that I have an issue and invalid tokens (I use Keycloak and if my Keycloak is restarted then all old tokens are invalid) are never removed (you can see it in [issue #9477](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/9477)) so I started debuging whole process of authorization in `ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction`. I found that tokens are saved per user of the application A. It means that every user of the application A has its own token for authorization to the application B. But this is not my intended behavior I want to use only one token in the application A for consuming a resource from the application B.

I think that I found two solutions but both of them are not optimal.

Solution 1.:
Add another default request after `ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction` which replaces user `Authentication` in attributes by an application `Authentication`. Problem is that it dependes on an  internal implemention of `ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction` which use a private attribute `AUTHENTICATION_ATTR_NAME = Authentication.class.getName();`.

```java
  return WebClient.builder()
      .apply(oauth2Client.oauth2Configuration())
      .defaultRequest(spec -> spec.attributes(attr -> 
           attr.put(AUTHENTICATION_ATTR_NAME, new CustomApplicaitonAuthentication())
        )
      .build();
```

Solution 2.:
Use a custom implementation of `OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` instead of default `AuthenticatedPrincipalOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` (which I have to do anyway because of the issue with removing invalid tokens) where I ignore user's `Authentication` and I use a custom application `Authentication`.

```java
@Override
public <T extends OAuth2AuthorizedClient> T loadAuthorizedClient(String clientRegistrationId, Authentication principal,
                                                                        HttpServletRequest request) {
  return this.authorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient(clientRegistrationId, new CustomApplicaitonAuthentication());
}

@Override
public void saveAuthorizedClient(OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient, Authentication principal,
                                    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
  this.authorizedClientService.saveAuthorizedClient(authorizedClient, new CustomApplicaitonAuthentication());
}
```

But I think that both my solutions are not optimal. Is there another way how to do it more straightforward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution because I needed to run it without a servlet request (messaging, scheduler etc.). Therefore I needed to update it and use the `AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` instead of the default `DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager`. Then I reallized that it does the same thing like I need.

```java
 @Bean
 WebClient buildWebClient(
      OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager oAuth2AuthorizedClientManager,
      OAuth2AuthorizationFailureHandler oAuth2AuthorizationFailureHandler,
      String clientName) {

    final ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2Client = new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
        oAuth2AuthorizedClientManager);
    oauth2Client.setDefaultClientRegistrationId(clientName);
    oauth2Client.setAuthorizationFailureHandler(oAuth2AuthorizationFailureHandler);

    return WebClient.builder()
        .apply(oauth2Client.oauth2Configuration())
        .build();
  }


  @Bean
  public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager
      (ClientRegistrationRepository clients, OAuth2AuthorizedClientService service, OAuth2AuthorizationFailureHandler authorizationFailureHandler) {
    AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager manager =
        new AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clients, service);
    manager.setAuthorizationFailureHandler(authorizationFailureHandler);
    return manager;
  }

  @Bean
  public OAuth2AuthorizationFailureHandler resourceServerAuthorizationFailureHandler(
      OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {
    return new RemoveAuthorizedClientOAuth2AuthorizationFailureHandler(
        (clientRegistrationId, principal, attributes) -> 
          authorizedClientService.removeAuthorizedClient(clientRegistrationId, principal.getName()));
  }
```

We had to add a custom `OAuth2AuthorizationFailureHandler` because if you do not use this constructor `ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository, OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository)` and you use a custom `OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` then it is not configured and you have to do it manually.

Comment: A short question and I really would love to get an answer to that. ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction is for MVC context, or to say it different: If I use WebClient in an MVC context. 
And I use ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction for a webflux context?